# Doesn't VSTS support automatic releases when tags are added?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I try to set up continuous delivery with VSTS and Azure with the following workflow:

1. Build on every commit to master (CI)
2. Create new release (and deploy) when a release tag is added (CD)

I have looked into:

- [This answer suggesting to check the box, which doesn't
  work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51058020/3282).
- [An other answer which configures the build, but I want to use a release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51682027/3282).
- [And this one, which adds a custom build task, but does not use releases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44535973/3282).

The build part works fine, and I can create a new release manually. But I can't get the release manager to create a new release when a new tag is created.

I have configured the deployment trigger like this, but it doesn't trigger on new tags even when the `Create a release when tags are added to an existing build`:

[image: Continuous deployment trigger]

I have tried `Build tags` variations as `refs/tags/v*`, `refs/tags/v\*`, `v*`, `v\*`, and specific tags like `prod`.

My build only reports `Tags set for release trigger did not match the tags in build branch`, which isn't very helpful:

[image: Deployments]

Comment: Tags specified in release definition Build branch filter is the Build tag as jessehouwing mentions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion is about the type of Tags. **Build tags** are actually defined on the Build, not in Git. They're not the same thing as a **Git tag**.

You can set the Build Tags through the REST API or through the UI (add tags on the Build Details page).

For more information, see:

- [Controlling build quality using Build Tags and VSTS Release Management](https://roadtoalm.com/2016/07/08/controlling-build-quality-using-build-tags-and-vsts-release-management/)
- [Tags - Add Build Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/tags/add%20build%20tag?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

In order to release based on tags, I think you may need to configure a CI build to trigger in the tag, then feed that into the release workflow. There is no way, without custom scripts, to promote the Build automatically by pushing a Git tag.